# How to put two "while" loops together in this case?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to set `max_chapter` and do functions until chapter number reaches the `max_chapter`. Then, book number increased by 1 and go through the same function until the chapter number reaches the `max_chapter`.

For example, Book 1 - Chapter 1~20, the Book turns out to be Book 2 and do functions Book 2 - Chapter 1~20,... and so on.

Here is a part of my code that I have the question about:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator

def start(max_book):
    word_list = []
    book = 1
    chapter = 1
    while book <= max_book:
        url = ('http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL='
               + str(book) + '&CN=' + str(chapter) + '&CV=99')
        while chapter <= 1:
            source_code = requests.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
            for bible_text in soup.findAll('font', {'class': 'tk4l'}):
                content = bible_text.get_text()
                words = content.lower().split()
                for each_word in words:
                    word_list.append(each_word)
            chapter += 1
        else:
            book += 1
    print(word_list)
start(1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by putting them together?

Comment: oh... you know I want to scrab all the texts from chapter 1~ 20 in book 1 and move on to chapter 1 of book 2 and do the same thing. So, I think the str(chapter) and str(book) both should increase in order. no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC , you need to read first 20 chapters from each book.

```
def Readchapters(max_books,max_chapters):
    book=1
    chapter=1
    while book <= max_books:

        while chapter<=max_chapters:
             print "reading book :",book ,"Chapter : ",chapter
             url = 'http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL={}&CN={}&CV=99'.format(book, chapter)
             source_code = requests.get(url).text
             soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
             '''
             #do your scraping here
             ................................
             ................................
             '''       
             chapter+=1 #move to next chapter
        book += 1 #move to next book
        chapter=1 #reset the chapter back
Readchapters(2,20)
```

output

```
reading book : 1 Chapter :  1
reading book : 1 Chapter :  2
reading book : 1 Chapter :  3
reading book : 1 Chapter :  4
reading book : 1 Chapter :  5
reading book : 1 Chapter :  6
reading book : 1 Chapter :  7
reading book : 1 Chapter :  8
reading book : 1 Chapter :  9
reading book : 1 Chapter :  10
reading book : 1 Chapter :  11
reading book : 1 Chapter :  12
reading book : 1 Chapter :  13
reading book : 1 Chapter :  14
reading book : 1 Chapter :  15
reading book : 1 Chapter :  16
reading book : 1 Chapter :  17
reading book : 1 Chapter :  18
reading book : 1 Chapter :  19
reading book : 1 Chapter :  20
reading book : 2 Chapter :  1
reading book : 2 Chapter :  2
reading book : 2 Chapter :  3
reading book : 2 Chapter :  4
reading book : 2 Chapter :  5
reading book : 2 Chapter :  6
reading book : 2 Chapter :  7
reading book : 2 Chapter :  8
reading book : 2 Chapter :  9
reading book : 2 Chapter :  10
reading book : 2 Chapter :  11
reading book : 2 Chapter :  12
reading book : 2 Chapter :  13
reading book : 2 Chapter :  14
reading book : 2 Chapter :  15
reading book : 2 Chapter :  16
reading book : 2 Chapter :  17
reading book : 2 Chapter :  18
reading book : 2 Chapter :  19
reading book : 2 Chapter :  20
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, I think the str(chapter) and str(book) both should increase in order. no?

You simply just need to include the construction of the url inside the inner while loop to ensure that the url is updated with the new chapter number.

```
while book <= max_book:
    while chapter <= 1:
        url = 'http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL={}&CN={}&CV=99'.format(book, chapter)
```

Comment: Note: the `chapter <= 1` will still restrict you from being able to get all 20 chapters but that is a separate issue

Comment: yes for that I can just change to 20. I just wanted to check if it works properly,, so, if I set that to 1 and run it with start(2). Then, it should be able to get me the first chapters of the first two books but it still only gives me the chapter one of the very first book.

Comment: @YunTaeHwang - Did you change the order of the inner while loop and url as per this answer?